# Как передать переменную среды от компилятора в CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake, кросс-компиляция

Имеется проект, который мы будем собирать кросскомпилятором на линуксе под windows. При этом если мы спрашиваем у компилятора переменную среды (`getenv()`) то он нам выдает нужные (под вином), но `cmake`, конечно, этих переменных не знает, так как это, все таки на линукс. Как можно сообщить `cmake`-у значение переменной окружения от компилятора?

Comment: Ничего не понятно, `getenv` это из C-рантайма, т.е. её используем во время исполнения приложения. CMake используется для генерации проектных файлов, которые будут использованы для сборки приложения. Здесь ещё далеко до исполнения.

Comment: @ixSci в том то и дело! Мне нужна эта переменная, как и где я могу ее взять для CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Я всё ещё не понимаю, о чём Вы говорите. Приведите пример, с конкретной переменной и как Вы её хотите использовать.

Comment: @ixSci ок: хочу получить переменную WINDIR, чтобы с помощью cmake правильно установить откомпилированную библиотеку.

Comment: Так если Вы на Linux, откуда там взяться WINDIR? Куда Вы на Linux собираетесь устанавливать библиотеку, которая собрана под Windows?

Comment: @ixSci я же писал про вино

Comment: Ну, тогда пишите в CMake файле `$ENV{WINDIR}` и устанавливайте, если Вы на Win. Понимаете, Вы выдаёте информацию какими-то странными порциями, в результате чего Вам очень сложно помочь.

Comment: @ixSci порциями? Ну вот что я написал в комментах, чего небыло в вопросе? И что ваша команда должна, по вашему выдать на линуксе?

Comment: @ixSci я так понял вы не знаете что такое вино - это wine - вино это просто буквальный перевод названия проги

Comment: Я впервые вижу, чтобы wine кто-то называл вином. Имена собственные не переводятся. Что касается всего остального: ясно не стало. Если Вы на Linux, и у Вас нет WINDIR, значит его не нужно использовать! Как Вы устанавливаете библиотеку? `make install`? Значит нужно выставлять `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` в значение, которое нужно. Я всё ещё не понимаю вопроса, причём тут переменные окружения?

Comment: @ixSci раз не видели - это не означает что так не делают. И то что имена не переводят - мы не на конкурсе граматики: постоянно можно увидить такие слова как: хэдэры, компилить и т.д. Хотя таких слов нет - это просто слэнг. Но не об этом. Еще раз пишу, это было в вопросе, но: кросскомпилятор! Когда я его спрашиваю переменную WINDIR - он мне дает значение именно этой переменной, а когда я устанавливаю что-то по этому пути, оно устанавливается в wine